# How to close Redis result backend connection in Celery?

Tags: redis, celery

I am using Pytest to test a Flask app that is integrated with a Celery app that has a Redis result backend, and I am getting the following errors from GitHub workflow action.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.17/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py", line 3848, in bindparam_string
    if self._bind_translate_re.search(name):
ResourceWarning: unclosed <socket.socket fd=41, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=6, laddr=('127.0.0.1', 33576), raddr=('127.0.0.1', 6379)>
```

It seems to me that the problem is due to connections to the Redis backend is not closed properly in the Flask app fixture teardown process. I tried using the following setup in the Flask app fixture to fix the problem without success.

```py
@pytest.fixture
def flask_app(tmp_path, monkeypatch):
    
    # Some other code here

    app = create_app()

    # Reset the database
    with app.app_context():
        db.drop_all()
        db.create_all()

    yield app

    with app.app_context():
        celery_app: Celery = app.extensions["celery"]

        celery_app.backend.client.close()
        celery_app.backend.result_consumer.stop()
        celery_app.backend.cleanup()

        celery_app.close()
```

Does anyone have a valid solution?

Thanks in advance.